# How do I alter the contents of IDictionary using LINQ (C# 3.0)

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-3.0, idictionary

How do I alter the contents of an IDictionary using C# 3.0 (Linq, Linq extensions) ?

```
var enumerable = new int [] { 1, 2};
var dictionary = enumerable.ToDictionary(a=>a,a=>0);
//some code
//now I want to change all values to 1 without recreating the dictionary
//how it is done?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not nearly as clear as other ways, but it should work fine:

```
dictionary.Keys.ToList().ForEach(i => dictionary[i] = 0);
```

My other alternative would have been to make a ForEach extension method similar to this:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            action(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
dictionary.ForEach(kvp => kvp.Value = 0);
```

This won't work in this case though, as Value cannot be assigned to.

Comment: So basically, I would never use the first piece of code in reality. The extension method can be great, but as Value cannot be assigned to, dictionaries don't allow for much.

Comment: Not as clear *and* less efficient (creates a cloned list of the keys, and does 2 iterations instead of 1)... a winner!

Answer (score 4):

LINQ is a query dialect - it isn't directly a mutation language.

To change the values of an existing dictionary, `foreach` is probably your friend:

```
foreach(int key in dictionary.Keys) {
    dictionary[key] = 1;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice if it was also a mutation language?

Comment: This gives a runtime error about the collection changing during the enumeration, and that the foreach loop cannot continue.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var item in dictionary.Keys)
    dictionary[item] = 1;
```

I wonder why you might a need doing such a thing, though.

Comment: It was an oversimplification.